# Overloading unary minus operator without member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following program:

```
//Operator overloading of unary minus operator- with and without member function

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class test{
    int x;
    public:
    test(){

    }
    test(int h){
        this->x=h;
    }
    friend void operator- (test);
    void showData(){
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};
void operator- (test a){
     test *ptr=&a;
     ptr->x=-ptr->x;
}
int main(){
    test t1(7);
    operator-(t1);
    t1.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

On executing, this prints 7 instead of -7 on online compilers as well as Visual Studio Code on machine. Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: When you change `a` (via a pointless pointer usage) in your operator, do you think its actually changing `t1` in `main` ? It's not. You're value-passing the argument to that function. All your changing is the content of `a`, not `t1` in `main`.

Comment: Can you please explain in little more clearer terms ? @WhozCraig

Comment: Also, when I introduce pointers, doesn't it change the value permanently? @WhozCraig

Comment: I tried a little and I figured out that using test & instead of test works, however, can someone please explain what is the issue in using test instead of test& and what is  the difference between test and test& ?

Comment: What is your pointer *pointing to* ? It's pointing to `a`, which is already just a copy of the original argument passed *by value* because of how your parameter list is declared. For what its worth, this operator is odd anyway. Unary minus should (a) make a copy (which you already have covered), (b) negate that copy, and (c) return the now-negated copy as a value-result. I.e `test operator -(test arg)`

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with overloading an operator - it works exactly the same as if the function had a normal name, like "negate". (On a slightly related note, a unary minus that modifies its arguments and doesn't return anything would be very surprising, and most people would consider it a bug.)

Answer (score 0):

You need  `test&` not `test` if you want to do that.  You probably shouldn't; unary minus shouldn't mutate its argument, it should return a modified one.

Comment: I tried a little and I figured out that using test & instead of test works, however, can someone please explain what is the issue in using test instead of test& and what is the difference between test and test&

Comment: @love `test` is a value, `test&` is a reference.   It should be covered pretty early on in any "learn to program in C++" text.  You can also google what is a reference in C++.